# How Do I Update the Values in a ListBox Using a List Filled with Values From Excel?

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, list, pysimplegui

I am trying to figure out how to update the values in a PySimpleGui Listbox by using a list that has been updated with values that have been pulled from an Excel file. When I run this though it just ends up running and crashing.

This code is going to be used in a much larger project, but I wanted to play around with it in a different file before trying to implement it into the larger project.

Here is the code that I have built.

```py
import pandas as pd
import PySimpleGUI as psg

workbook = pd.read_excel('Connection Diagrams.xlsx', 'Active Diagrams')

list = []

layout = [[psg.Listbox(values = list,size=(20,20), key = 'l')],
        [psg.Button('Get')]]
win = psg.Window('',layout)

i = 0
while True:

    event, values = win.read()

    if event == psg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

    if event == 'Get':

        while i < 789:

            if workbook['Type:'][i] == 'SP':

                list.append(workbook['Connection Diagram:'][i])

        i += 1

        win['l'].update(values = list)

win.close()
```

Comment: Should place line `i += 1` into `while` block, and not using python keyword `list` as variable.

Comment: That fixed it, thank you!